# Streaming DAO Results in Java (Design Pattern)

Tags: java, design-patterns, jdbc, export, dao

Given following situation:

- DAO which queries all rows from a table and maps them to a list of domain objects (pure `JDBC`)
- A service which processes the list resulting from the DAO and renders certain list elements formatted to a file.

The problem here is that all the DAO results are hold in memory which becomes dangerous as the tables grows.

**Question:** Is there a pattern to read objects from a DAO in a streaming way that the service processes only one element at a time, writes it to the file output stream and then requests the next element from the result set? Is it in general a good idea to use a `ResultSet` as a return type of a DAO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you exposed the results set, which you shouldn't, you still don't get streaming semantics by default. For that you need to do something like this:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
              java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

You should encapsulate this within your DAO, you could return a custom iterator to process the results.

See the [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) on the topic of streaming results.

Comment: Thx! I had the same feeling that it's not a good idea to expose ResultSets. The iterator is a good tip! Still I'm wondering if it's worth the effort just for separating (a little) BL from the DB query logic. I assume in general people just mix this up in one class?

Comment: Generally BL and DB logic are not intertwined. Returning a custom iterator from your DAO would be the simplest and cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to do a paged query, you can either get a total count of rows and then choose a page size and use your database tools (rowid for oracle) to get the pages until you have all rows or you can just keep querying until you get no results.

Comment: What how would the DAO interface look like then? Please keep in mind that I would like to keep a separation between business logic (Service) and query logic (DAO).

Answer (score 0):

So you only process a given row once? You could mark that row as processed in the database, and only select on rows that are unprocessed. Alternatively, you could move processed rows to a different table.

Comment: Your suggestions would imply at least one update per row. This sounds not very performant when you have e.g. some 100K or million rows.

Comment: Good point. Other options on this page look a lot more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd *never* return a `ResultSet` from a DAO, keep the data logic encapsulated in the data class.

I'd probably also never write a DAO method that returned the whole table, seems just a bit too generic. Instead I'd probably write a DAO method called `dumpToFile(File f)` that did the whole job internally. This way the DAO can read records one at a time and write them to file.

Comment: Assume that the service is doing certain validations, skipping some records due to business rules and formatting them. When applying the concept of separation of concerns these are not things to be done in a DAO. That's why I'm asking.